# Why isn't Django connecting to SQL Server 2019?

Tags: django, django-pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure, django-mssql-backend

Please see below screenshots as to existing configuration (password hidden due to security reasons).

[Databases Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0txK.png)

[Python Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxRNN.png)

The error that is returned when I attempt to run  the server is either SQL Server v15 is not supported or Django 3.0 is not supported. Does anyone have the same issue and a clean-cut solution for resolution?

EDIT: I have changed the environment to remove django-pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure and django-pyodbc-azure-2019. The environment still has django-mssql-backend installed. However it is saying that 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend.

Answer (score 1):

`django-pyodbc-azure` hasn't been maintained in quite some time.

The current maintained fork, which supports both Django 3.0 and SQL Server 2019, is `django-mssql-backend`:

https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend

Looking at the image you included of Python packages (and please, in the future, just use text!), be sure you uninstall `django-pyodbc`, `django-pyodbc-azure`, and `django-pyodbc-azure-2019`.

A full walk through is available here: https://www.pyphilly.org/django-and-sql-server-2020-edition/

I use it on many projects and it works well. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this information. I have changed the environment to remove django-pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure and django-pyodbc-azure-2019. 

The environment still has django-mssql-backend installed. However it is saying that 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend.

Comment: Can you run a `pip freeze` and make sure that `django-mssql-backend` is present? What version is it? For example, my freeze list has `django-mssql-backend==2.7.0`.

Comment: I've added a link to the answer with a full walk through.